# Empty layout when running app

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-xml

I am trying to create a linear layout for my android app. Inside of this linear layout there are two other layouts, a relative layout and another linear layout. These two layouts have a weight of 1. When I am looking at my layout at the graphical_layout everything looks fine. But when I am running my app on my phone or a virtual device I just see an empty layout.

This is how it should look (it is actually a screenshot of the graphical_layout):

[image]

This is how it looks on the virtual device and my phone:

[image]

Here is my xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#EEEEEE"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    tools:context="xx.xx.counter.MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/cpb"
            android:rotation="270" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="@string/number"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="70sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/button2"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:rotation="180" />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/number" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code of the cpb.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3.5"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="60.0"
        android:useLevel="false">
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#AAAAAA"
            android:centerColor="#AAAAAA"
            android:endColor="#AAAAAA"
            android:type="linear"/>
    </shape>
</item> 
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="4"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="20.0">
        <gradient 
            android:startColor="#ff8800"
            android:centerColor="#ff8800"
            android:endColor="#ff8800"
            android:type="linear"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

If I change the height and width of my parent linear layout from fill_parent or match_parent to wrap_content it does not look how I want it to look. But I can see something when I am running the app so I do not think that it is a problem with the onCreate() – Methode.

So what is wrong with my layout, and what do I have to do, so that it looks like I want it to look?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with your layout. It works on my nexus 5 phone.  Try change

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Also , make sure you have setContentView on Activity OnCreate

Comment: I have setContentView on Activity OnCreate. When I change the parent linear layout to width and height wrap_content I see something when I am running the app.
I have also tried your solution, and the 0 is displayed when I am running the app. Nothing more just the 0...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue either.

If you are using weigth it's recommended to use the 0dp width, but you could try to add the weightSum property to your main LinearLayout.

```
android:weightSum="3"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works. I don’t think that this is a perfect one, but it works for now.

I put a FrameLayout around the other layouts, so that the structure of my code now looks like this:

```
   <FrameLayout>
        <LinearLayout>
            <RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

With this solution I got a warning, that the LinearLayout, which was actually my main layout, is not necessary. But I think it is necessary, because otherwise I cannot use layout_weight.

Can someone tell me, why it’s working now but not without the FrameLayout?